# restore database from backup

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database called IND_Master which I have backed up in a file named "IND_Master.bak".

I would like to restore this into another database called 'IND_test" so that they are identical. both the data and structure needs to be identical.

Can someone either give me the script or tell me how to do this from sql server..even if it means creating another IND_master and changing the name to IND_test.

Comment: You can't merge two databases..if you are looking to keep schema similar for both databases,then why not keep the same database

Comment: yes I dont mind that. even if it means creating another IND_master and changing the name to IND_test. then it will be indentical.

Comment: I have changed your question word as per chris answer ,please revert back this change if this is not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will restore your backup file to a new database called `IND_test` and rename the logical file names accordingly. Obviously you'll need to alter the paths though.

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [IND_test]
  FROM DISK = N'C:\SQL\Backups\IND_Master.bak' WITH FILE = 1,
  MOVE N'IND_master' TO N'C:\SQL\Data\IND_test.mdf',
  MOVE N'IND_master_log' TO N'C:\SQL\Logs\IND_test_log.ldf'
GO    
ALTER DATABASE [IND_test]
MODIFY FILE (NAME = 'IND_master', NEWNAME = 'IND_test')
GO
ALTER DATABASE [IND_test]
MODIFY FILE (NAME = 'IND_master_log', NEWNAME = 'IND_test_log')
GO
```